# How represent total number of csv file rows with conditional logic in tableau

Tags: csv, tableau-api

i have csv file that contain different user_id and associated tweets here is dummy csv for better understanding:

[image]

How i represent the daily number of tweets as well as the daily number of users, with tableau chart(or any other representation form which efficient visualize the user case)

For above example

For Date 7/12/2017 Total no of tweets are 5 and number of users:2

For Date 8/12/2017 Total no of tweets are 4 and number of users:4

For Date 9/12/2017 Total no of tweets are 3 and number of users:2

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to?

- Drag Date in 'Columns'. Right click it and select 'More' -> Custom ->
  'Detail': 'Month / Day / Year'
- Drag 'User_id' in 'Rows'. Right click it and select Measure -> Count
  (Distinct) Drag 'Tweet_id' in 'Rows'.
- Right click it and select Measure -> Count Right click below graph
  and select 'Dual Axis'

Comment: Please don't forget to let us know if this is the solution you were expecting as it'll surely help others in case they face similar issue.